# JavaScript dynamic iFrame not showing up

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm using JS to build some HTML that includes the new iframe syntax from YouTube.

When someone clicks a link on the page to a YouTube video, JS checks the document size and if it's big enough, will open up a lightbox-style box on the page and play the video there.

When I test it out, it opens the HTML but the space is just white and the source code shows an empty `<iframe>` element.

Is there a problem with trying to dynamically add an iframe to a page?

Here is the relevant part of the JS:

```
iframe = '<iframe width="'+defaults.width+'" height="'+defaults.height+'" src="'+vidsrc+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
container = '<div class="videopow-overlay"><div class="videopow-container">' + iframe + '</div></div>';

$("body").prepend( container );
```

Here is what gets output:

```
<div class="videopow-overlay">
  <div class="videopow-container">
    <iframe width="800" height="485" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phzvyIQWCo8?hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
      <html><head></head><body></body></html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your vidurl, i think there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change vidsrc from:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phzvyIQWCo8?hd=1
```

to

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/phzvyIQWCo8?hd=1
```

Comment: Oh god that was totally it. Thanks!